# Как правильно писать: "Генеральная прокуратура" или "генеральная прокуратура"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Как правильно писать: "Генеральная прокуратура" или "генеральная прокуратура" в публицистических статьях? Это ведь не полное официальное название. И как написать: "Генпрокуратура" или "генпрокуратура"? В справочниках различают официальное и неофициальное название учреждений. Я так понимаю: если изменена хотя бы буква в официальном названии, то это уже неофициальное. Скажем, официальное: Генеральная прокуратура Республики Казахстан. Тогда *Генеральная прокуратура* и *Генеральная прокуратура Казахстана* уже неофициальные названия и можно писать со строчной?

Answer (score 1):

Первое слово полного официального названия учреждения всегда пишется с большой буквы. "Генеральная прокуратура Казахстана", на мой взгляд, тоже является официальным названием (альтернативным), поэтому лучше будет написать с большой буквы.
В это же время "генпрокуратура" - это уже точно не официальное название, и тут допустима строчная буква.

Answer (score 0):

Статистика. В Нацкорпусе в 989 из 1017 вхождений слово "Генпрокуратура" написано с прописной, из них только в 64 вхождениях оно стоит в начале предложения. В 519 из 551 вхождения название "Генеральная прокуратура" написано с прописной, из них только в 36 вхождениях оно стоит в начале предложения. Название "Генеральная прокуратура Казахстана" встречается только в газетном корпусе и только 6 раз, из них только один раз оно написано  со строчной.  "Генпрокуратура Казахстана" со строчной найдено 1 раз в основном корпусе и 1 раз в газетном.

Вывод: пишите с прописной — не ошибетесь.